# Student answer evaluation

Tags: nlp

Given a question, with some model answers and their grades, and possibly other 'learning material' content.

What tools or technologies can be used, to implement a system that evaluates a student answer?

I am new to machine learning.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, however I am afraid that if someone has a good answer to that question, he/she would be way better of building said tools and a billion dollars start-up around it.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that could be leveraged - use all the model answers and learning material, find some sort of semantic similarity between all that text and the student answer. The higher the similarity with a model answer with a specific grade tag, the higher the probability of assigning that answer that particular grade. You can couple this with a metric of similarity between the student answer and learning material, more similarity between the two, higher probability of a better grade.

This seems like a very hard problem considering it is still a very active area of research in NLP, Some tools or concepts that might be interesting to you - Latent Semantic Analysis, word embeddings, text/document similarity, semantic coherence.